# How to get the file from another folder in project by calling method from JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

```
@WebService(name = "ManageSearchDataPortType", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData", serviceName = "ManageSearchData", portName = "ManageSearchDataPort", wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/ManageSearchData.wsdl")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
import com.xyz.SearchDataRequest;
import com.xyz.SearchDataResponse;

@XmlSeeAlso({ ObjectFactory.class, com.abc.ObjectFactory.class, com.abc..ObjectFactory.class, com.abc..ObjectFactory.class })
public class ManageSearchDataService {

    @WebResult(name = "searchDataResponse", partName = "searchDataResponse", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData")
    @WebMethod(action = "http://example.com/wsdl/ManageABC/2008/10/22#searchData")
    public SearchDataResponse searchData(@WebParam(name = "searchDataRequest", partName = "searchDataRequest", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData")
        SearchDataRequest searchDataRequest) {
        ClassLoader loader = ManagePriceLinePortTypeImpl.class.getClassLoader();
        java.io.InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("logHandling.properties"); // stream as null 
        LoggingFramework.initialise(stream); 
        SearchDataResponse response =new SearchDataResponse();
        response.setErrorCode("OK");
        return response;
    }

     public void test();
     {
     System.out.println("TEST  Method");
     }
    }
```

In above code snippet i was trying to read property file from outside the src location but i am getting file not found exception because of null stream.

HeaderClass is just normal call which contains getMPLNHeader static method.

Please anyone have any idea how to do this let me know.

[image: please check attached project file structure as in image]

```
package com.test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.xyz.SearchDataRequest;
import com.aaa.ManageSearchDataService;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JunitTestClass {
    ManageSearchDataService mockObj ;

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        SearchDataRequest searchDataRequest= new SearchDataRequest();
        searchDataRequest.setStandardHeader(HeaderClass.getMPLNHeader("ASV"));
        SearchDataResponse respose =mockObj.searchData(searchDataRequest); 
        System.out.println("=== "+respose.getErrorCode());      

    }

    }
```

Comment: Shouldnt these files be in a resource folder under src ?

Comment: @yashpandey they don't need to in this case since it seems to be a properties file for a server ( hint the `WAR` folder ). 
@addy This is a MOCK so you have to prepae the files needed. You have to think of it in an seperate and closed out area. Specify the complete path to the file and it should work.